# Post-increment vs Assignment in C++ operation precedence table

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I stumbled upon https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

On the chart, I see that post-increment operator (++) is way above assignment operator (=).

[image]

However, I know that

```
int a[] = {10,20};
int* b = &a[0];

*(b++) = 5;

cout << a[0] << endl; // 5
cout << a[1] << endl; // 20
cout << *b << endl; // 20, now points to a[1]
```

I always take it for grant that post-increment happens after the assignment operator. However, if I follow the operation precedence chart, then isn't post-increment suppose to happen before `=` operation? Isn't the answer suppose to be `a={10, 5}` rather than `a={5, 20}`?

Comment: Instead of using `int` to examine the sequential behavior of the operators applied, you might write a test class overloading all these operators in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Precedence" is misleading. It has little to do in general with *evaluation order* (what happens first), but instead determines what is the operand of each operator for the purpose of evaluation. But let's examine your example.

```
*(b++) = 5;
```

This means that `5` is to be assigned to the lvalue on the left. And since C++17, we know that `5` is evaluated entirely before `*(b++)`. Prior to that, they could be evaluated in any order.

Now, `b++` has the meaning of "increment `b`, but evaluate to its *previous* value". So `b++` may cause the increment to happen prior to the assignment taking place, yes, but the value of `(b++)` is the address before the increment happened. And that is why `b` is updated to point at the next element, while modifying the current one, in one expression.

Comment: Oh, I see. *(b++) is actually evaluated before assignment operator, but because post-increment is basically a function that return value before increment (in this case, &a[0]), so the result is seemed as if post-increment is done after assignment.

Then, wouldn't that means post-increment operator requires extra memory (to store the returned original value)?

Comment: @pbeta - Maybe, maybe not. For the case in your question, a compiler is allowed to actually do the increment after the assignment. The reason is that the observable behavior of your program remains the same, and so under the as-if rule, such an optimization is possible. If it was an overloaded operator, it would probably incur a bit more space. But either way, it's not something I'd fret over if I really needed a post increment.

Answer (score 2):

Post increment (`b++`) increments `b`, **then returns the previous value of `b`**.

Pre increment (`++b`) increments `b`, **then returns the new value of `b`**.

To get the behavior you're expecting, change from post-increment to pre-increment.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a[] = {10, 20};
  int *b = &a[0];

  *(++b) = 5;

  std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << *b << std::endl;
}
```

Yields the following output:

```
10
5
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Table is Correct. And there is no confusion for the result.
Just remember the fact that post increment(PI) or decrement(DI), perform +1 or -1 update after the current statement containing PI or DI.

***(b++) = 5;**

1st b++ will take place first as it is in parentheses. but **b** didn't move next yet. As compiler always remember in post operations that it would perform it after the current statement. so it is like:

*b = 5;   // a[0]=5; compiler remembered b=b+1; to be executed.

so now b = b+1;

hence b is now pointing at a[1];